# Sublime 3: last session not saved

Tags: session, sublimetext3

So I have reinstalled my Ubuntu to newer version and then I migrated sublime 3 configuration that I used. Everything seem to be saved like it was before, but it looks like sublime just do not save a session that it was at.

Every time I close sublime, when I open, I always get one file opened that I had used before at some time. It does not matter what I had opened recently, it always opens same file.

To be specific, it is `bashrc` file (if that matters at all).

Now if I reopen sublime, then close `bashrc` file, then open project, when I reopen again, I do not even see that project was added. I can't use alt+ctrl+p, because it does not remember that I even opened any project.

I looks like session is fixed on one state somehow.

Sublime build I'm using is: `3126`

**Update**:
When migrating sublime settings, I copied this directory `sublime-text-3/Packages/User` (that comes from `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User`). It had settings files and some custom snippets.

Comment: most likely a permissions issue then on `~/.config/sublime-text-3` and its subfolders - any errors in the ST console that it failed to save any files?

Comment: It seems the issue is that for some configurations/plugins sublime is looking for old paths that had been used in my previous OS. I get things like: `no such file or directoty /home/user1/.config/`. When my actual user now is `user2` (`user1` was used in previous OS). I thought configuration just looks for relative paths. Is there a way to somehow reset paths to look for current one that sublime is installed?

Comment: Try open some files in the project and then use "close project". Restart sublime and check if this time it opens all files.

Comment: **Note: (added 2023-02-17)** Some content in this thread may reference stale links to the SublimeText docs. Readers may experience better results by replacing **BEFORE** [http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest) with **AFTER** [https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide). Also known as: "Sublime Text Community Documentation"

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue on linux. From https://web.archive.org/web/20191102071813/http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/getting_started/install.html

run the following command:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/.config/sublime-text-3
```